# Custom sorting of list based on date

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I got:

```
List<Comment> list = new ArrayList<Comment>();
```

My class Comment contains: id, name and date;
I got some function that adds specified Comments, but I would like to order after that my list by date descending. How to do it with this:

```
Collections.sort(list, comparator)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to implement a `Comparator<Comment>` that implements the `compare` method based on the date field, and pass this object to the `Collections.sort`.

Here's a complete example:

```
import java.util.*;

class Comment {
    String id, String name;
    Date date;

    public Comment(String id, String name, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }
}


class CommentComparator implements Comparator<Comment> {
    public int compare(Comment o1, Comment o2) {
        return o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
    }
}


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>() {{
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            add(new Comment("id1", "second", new Date(now)));
            add(new Comment("id2", "first", new Date(now - 1000)));
            add(new Comment("id3", "third", new Date(now + 1000)));
        }};

        Collections.sort(comments, new CommentComparator());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You already know what you need to do. Just implement de `Comparator`. It could be something like:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Comment>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Comment o1, Comment o2) {
                return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
            }
        });
```

*(You may need to check for nulls)*

Answer (score 0):

One option mentioned by fellows here is to implement custom Comparator for the comments. Alternative approach would be to implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in Comment class.

```
import java.util.*;

class Comment implements Comparable<Comment> {
    private String id, String name;
    private Date date;

    public Comment(String id, String name, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int compareTo(Comment comment) {
        return date.compareTo(o2.date); //Look Ma! Date is Comparable too!
    }

}


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>() {{
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            add(new Comment("id1", "second", new Date(now)));
            add(new Comment("id2", "first", new Date(now - 1000)));
            add(new Comment("id3", "third", new Date(now + 1000)));
        }};
        Collections.sort(comments);
    }
}
```

I have used some of the @aioobe code in my example.